# How to auto generate product SKU in MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring-boot, sku

I am working on a E-commerce website using Angular, Spring Boot, MySQL.
I am implementing a features to allow user to add a product for sale.
When user add a product how do you auto generate SKU in MySQL Or is there any other way to make SKU?

This how the product are stored in database:

[image]

[image]

I am ok with new suggestion with how to make SKU:

I have 8 product category in database:

[image]

User only choose Product Category.

Comment: Your question is confusing, what is the issue with current approach and what you mean by auto generated? How the auto generated one will differ from the current one?

Comment: *is there any other way to make SKU?* Use UUID().

Comment: @code_mechanic Currently all those products in database are inserted by me and those SKU are hardcoded. But in production I want SKU to be auto generated when a product is added by users into database. user only choose a product category. So If the category is Book then SKU will be BOOK-TECH-auto generated unique number like 1011. if the category is Bag then SKU will be BAG-auto generated unique number like 3033.

Comment: @Akina Yes that seems like a good solution. I just wanna know different solution to this problem. thank you

Comment: If you could use the `UUID` that's the best approach you can have but if you have to generate as per the logic you mentioned, then every solution will have pros and cons.

Comment: I personally wanted something like BOOK-TECH-(1000+primary key) So, basically a mysql function will take category as input then concatenate "BOOK-TECH-" + 1000+ "product primary key" then if product primary key 20 then SKU will be "BOOK-TECH-1020" But I wonder how do professional e-commerce or inventory management system make their SKU?

Comment: Well, see the answers to the duplicate question for viable approaches. However, pls do take heed of the warning in Erwin Brandstetter's answer: `This has been asked many times and the general idea is bound to fail in a multi-user environment - and a blog system sounds like exactly such a case.

So the best answer is: Don't. Consider a different approach.`

Comment: Thanks everyone for their response. I found the solution.